# Reddit to Twitter python bot error (python: praw & tweepy used)

Tags: python, tweepy, reddit, praw

I have a problem with this part of my code:

```
timeline = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items(1)
for submission in reddit.subreddit('StonerPhilosophy').top('hour' , limit=1):    
        if len(submission.title) <= 280:
            try:
                api.update_status(status = submission.title)
                sleep(120)
                for tweet in timeline:
                    api.update_status(status = 'Credits: Posted by /u/' + str(submission.author) + 'url: redd.it/' + str(submission.id) , in_reply_to_status_id = tweet.id)
            except:
                print('Fail')
        elif len(submission.title) <= 560:
            try:
                s = submission.title
                first_half  = s[0:len(s)//2]
                second_half = s[len(s)//2 if len(s)%2 == 0 else ((len(s)//2)+1):]

                api.update_status(status = first_half)
                for tweet in timeline:
                    api.update_status(status = second_half) , in_reply_to_status_id = tweet.id)

                sleep(120)

                for tweet in timeline:
                    api.update_status(status = 'Credits: Posted by /u/' + str(submission.author) + 'url: redd.it/' + str(submission.id)) , in_reply_to_status_id = tweet.id)
            except:
                print('Fail')
```

when I try to run it I get 'Invalid Syntax' as an error. The problem is with 'tweet.id' (but for some reason the second and the third, no problem with the first one... :/)

what i am doing with 'tweet.id' is basically getting the id of my last tweet so that i can reply to it with either the credits or the second part of the tweet (I have to break some tweet in two parts if they are longer than 280 char) and then another reply with the credits. I have been trying to fix this for hours :/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your API calls should look like, but assuming 
`api.update_status()` takes a status, and a tweetID; you are only passing it a status. If you look at the brackets on it,
`api.update_status(status = second_half)` is all that you would call, if it didn't fail during run because of the rest of the line.

you might have better luck with:

`api.update_status(status = second_half, in_reply_to_status_id = tweet.id)`

More information on your API/code would be helpful.

Comment: Since python is interpreted, not compiled it can be tricky to know if a line is valid until it is hit. If you move these `update_status` calls higher up in the program, just to try them with test values, it might be easier to see if they are well formed.